# Error Initializing Reducer while working in MERN stack

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm following along with Traversy Media's MERN stack course, on the redux section. I'm getting errors regarding the initialization of reducers, though I've checked my code against the instructor's code many times and can't find a difference.

I tried changing various import and export statements, sometimes gives unrelated errors that go away when I change it back.

Here is my itemReducer.js

```
import uuid from "uuid";
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: uuid(), name: "Eggs" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Milk" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Steak" },
    { id: uuid(), name: "Candy" }
  ]
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import itemReducer from "./itemReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  item: itemReducer
});
```

and ShoppingList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import uuid from "uuid";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems } from "../actions/itemActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ShoppingList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getIems();
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Button
          color="dark"
          style={{ marginBottom: "2rem" }}
          onClick={() => {
            const name = prompt("Enter Item");
            if (name) {
              this.setState(state => ({
                items: [...state.items, { id: uuid, name }]
              }));
            }
          }}
        >
          Add Item
        </Button>

        <ListGroup>
          <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
            {items.map(({ id, name }) => (
              <CSSTransition key={id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                <ListGroupItem>
                  <Button
                    className="remove-btn"
                    color="danger"
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState(state => ({
                        items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
                      }));
                    }}
                  >
                    &times;
                  </Button>
                  {name}
                </ListGroupItem>
              </CSSTransition>
            ))}
          </TransitionGroup>
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

ShoppingList.propTypes = {
  getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getItems }
)(ShoppingList);
```

expected result: I expect the http://localhost:3000 to load a shopping list with items that can be removed or added.

actual result: What I get is this error
`Error: Reducer "item" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why, is that when a store is created an `INIT` action is dispatched so that every reducer returns their initial state [source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/55f1d08000b1b064eaa933bbbd132230e53bcccb/src/createStore.js#L242), and in your case your reducer doesn't know how to deal with the `INIT` action (it returns undefined, and that's why you got the error)

you can fix this by adding a `default` case to your reducer:

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
        return state
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I think it worked, but now I'm getting the error "×
TypeError: this.props.getIems is not a function
ShoppingList.componentDidMount
src/components/ShoppingList.js:11
   8 | 
   9 | class ShoppingList extends Component {
  10 |   componentDidMount() {
> 11 |     this.props.getIems();
  12 |   }
  13 | 
  14 |   render() {"

Comment: Is that unrelated/should I open up a separate thread for that?

Comment: That's just a typo, your action dispatcher is called `getItems` not `getIems`

Comment: Oh my God, I'm so blind. Thank you so much for your time, this saved my day. Without all the help from S.O. I would be so lost.